# Как убить Task который долго выполняется?

Tags: c#, task

Есть запрос, который может выполняться до часа. Что бы не блокировать интерфейс пользователя, он проходит через Task. Если пользователю надоело ждать, надо этот запрос отменить. Как правильно это сделать, что бы соединение не висело целый час нагружая БД и пользователь их не создавал кучу? Может есть какие-то альтернативные варианты, кроме Task?

```
private void UpdateGrid(){
    SomeRows rows;
    Task task = new Task(() => 
    {
        rows = IDBConnectInstance.SelectRows();
    });
    task.ContinueWith(() =>
    {
        dataGridView.DataSource = rows;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

**UPD:**

Каких либо дополнительных точек нету, сам IDBConnectInstance представляет собой интерфейс из сторонней библиотеки. То есть он входит в функцию библиотеки `IDBConnectInstance.SelectRows` и останавливается в ожидании завершения. Если бы была возможность обработать `CancellationToken`, вопрос бы не возник.

```
IDBConnect
{
    SelectRows();
}

public class DBConnect: IDBConnect
{
    public List<SomeClass> SelectRows()
    {
        String query = "Очень долгий SELECT из БД";
        List<SomeClass> result = new List<SomeClass>();
        using(OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            dbconn.Open();

            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, dbconn);
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                SomeClass someClass = new someClass()
                {
                    SomeField = reader[0],
                    SomeField = reader[1],
                    ...
                }
                result.Add(someClass);
            }
            reader.Close();
            dbconn.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Пока есть только мысль вернуться на `Thread` и использовать устаревший `Thread.Abort()`;

Comment: Внутри кода есть какие либо точки опоры, какие либо циклы, которые проверяют отменена ли задача? Корректно так: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Убивать Task - дурной тон. Надо не Task убивать, а запрос отменять. Пожалуйста, уточните способ получения данных.

Comment: @Align, больше точек опоры нет, иначе бы воспользовался простой отменой CancellationToken и вопроса не возникло бы. Там сам код внутри отправляет запрос и ждет ответ долго.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, обновил ответ.

Comment: @AlexKrass он долго ждет на ExecuteReader() - или в цикле?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, на ExecuteReader.

Comment: А [`ExecuteReaderAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh223679(v=vs.110).aspx) не работает?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, должны по идее работать [вот такие конструкции](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/asynchronous.html).

Comment: @AlexKrass если begin-end работает - то и async должен работать, по-идее.

Comment: [Не то](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18090762/4267982)?

Comment: @AlexKrass вопрос на самом деле не про убиство таска, а про отмен долгой команды. Какую именно библиотеку вы используете? У нее есть возможность задать command timeout?

Comment: @PashaPash, dotconnect for oracle, как правильно меня подтолкнули к мысли Pavel Mayorov и Surfin Bird, там есть отмена запроса. По ссылке, которую я дал Выше, есть тема Halting Execution и `OracleCommand.Cancel()`. Думал обойтись без правки библиотеки с самим соединением. Видимо пока сделаю быструю заглушку через `Thread.Abort` и потом начну рефакторить под нормальную отмену. Было бы хуже, если бы это была сторонняя библиотека без исходников, так что возможно вопрос кому-то пригодился бы.

Comment: @AlexKrass IDBConnect и SelectRows реализованы у вас в коде? или в сторонней библиотеке? просто я глянул справку по dotconnect for oracle - и никаких IDBConnect  в ней нет. Т.е. если SelectRows - это ваш метод, и вы вы сами вызывает  dotconnect ExecuteReader - то почему бы просто не выставить таймаут команде?

Comment: @AlexKrass я к тому, что у вас в вопросе сказано что SelectRows менять нельзя. И тут же в комментах вы пишете - ок, без проблем, поменяю :)

Comment: @AlexKrass потому что если можно - то заменяете ExecuteReader на `Task.Factory.FromAsync<OracleDataReader>(command.BeginExecuteReader, command.EndExecuteReader)`, получаете нормальный асинхронный таск, ждете его с таймаутом, и если не дождались - отменяете команду. Если менять нельзя - то не повезло :(

Comment: @PashaPash, UI Описывает данные, которые ему нужны из базы, через мой написанный интерфейс IDBConnect. А вот его метод SelectRows реализовывает несколько поставщиков. Cейчас мой и один сторонней организации, хорошо есть обратная связь и у обоих dotconnect for oracle. Потом еще могут появится другие и не факт, что там будет связь с ними и эта же БД, не говоря уже о провайдере к ней. Поэтому в идеале, для меня это черный ящик и обрабатывать логику мне легче из полностью моего UI. Если это неправильно, значит буду пробрасывать флаг отмены и пускай сам поставщик решает, как и что с этим делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Желательно дать пользователю возможность отмены, по команде.

```
private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
private bool _isWorked = false;

private void CancelUpdateGrid()
{
    _tokenSource.Cancel();
}

private void UpdateGrid()
{
    if (_isWorked)
    {
       return;
    }

    _isWorked = true;

    SomeRows rows;

    // создаём CancellationTokenSource который отменит операцию
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // В задачу передадим нужный нам токен.
    Task task = Task.Run(() => 
    {
         var t = Thread.CurrentThread;
        using (cancellationSource.Token.Register(t.Abort))
        {
            rows = IDBConnectInstance.SelectRows();
        }
    }, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        dataGridView.DataSource = rows;
        _isWorked = false;
    });
}
```

Приведённый мною код упрощённый для понятия концепции с отменой.

Comment: А можете подсказать, почему данный пример иногда работает, а иногда нет? Вот пример, когда он не работает: на форме три кнопки и текстбокс, код формы и IDBConnectInstance: http://pastebin.com/nfDFXmDQ Не смотря на вызов Cancel, поток все равно продолжит работать.

Comment: Я подпраил немного код своего ответа. IDBConnectInstance.SelectRows() желательно должен поддерживать отмену. Я посмотрел ваш код по ссылке, для начала нужно добавить при каждой итерации цикла проверку на отмену токена Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

Comment: Спасибо, наверное самый лучший вариант из тех, что имеется для решения конкретно поставленной задачи "убить Task" без всяких отмен и переговоров.

Answer (score 1):

Цитирую [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997417(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Если родительская задача отменяет саму себя после запуска дочерней или вложенной задачи, вложенная (дочерняя) задача будет завершена, если она не имеет собственной логики отмены.

Соответственно, можно попробовать такой костыль: запускать родительскую задачу с таймером, из которой запускать вашу дочернюю. По истечении тайиера отменять родительскую, что, по идее, приведёт к отмене дочерней (если она не имеет собственной логики отмены ©)

Comment: Проверял на коде из MSDN, не получается, он даже простой бесконечный `while(true)` считает походу за логику отмены, а целый метод тем более. Первая задача повисает со статусом `RanToComplete`, даже принудительный `throw new Exception` не дает результатов на дочерний процесс.

Answer (score 1):

Типовой подход - [две задачи](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout). Если нужно непременно "убить", то имеет смысл явно запускать отдельный поток и у него вызывать Thread.Abort.

Comment: Thread.Abort — зло.

Comment: *"надо этот запрос отменить. Как правильно это сделать, что бы соединение не висело целый час нагружая БД и пользователь их не создавал кучу?"*

Comment: Из двух зол иногда приходится выбирать меньшую. А вопрос называется "Как убить Task который долго выполняется?" - если рассматривать именно "надо этот запрос отменить", то это совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: @AlexanderAlexeev из двух зол надо выбирать третье, а не меньшее